# Selecting subset of elements of an array/list with boolean indices

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, numpy

I have a list (or numpy array), let's call it `my_list` with length of `100`. I have another list, called `flag_list` with the same length consisting of 1s and 0s. I want my `new_list` be the elements of `my_list` whom have 1 in their corresponding position in flag_list. Somehow, to remove those who have 0 flag.

Is there a short way of doing this without writing a for loop?

I also have a 2d numpy array that I want to exclude some raws based on flags.

Thanks in advane

Comment: Lists and numpy arrays differ.  List comprehension can be used to index individual elements.  numpy arrays can be indexed with whole boolean arrays.  Read the https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing

Comment: For lists you can use `itertools.compress`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to accomplish this

```
my_list = list('abcde')
flag_list = [0,1,0,1,1]
new_list = [val for i, val in enumerate(my_list) if flag_list[i]]
print(new_list)
```

Outputs

```
['b', 'd', 'e']
```

Answer (score 2):

Boolean indexing can be used for this. Convert list of 0,1s to array of booleans and then do indexing. Below solution does the job with simple numpy operations, without any higher order functions or comprehensions.

```
import numpy as np

# generate dummy data
my_list = np.arange(10)
flag_list = np.random.randint(2,size=(10,))

print("  my_list",  my_list)
print("flag_list", flag_list)

bool_list = flag_list == 1
print("bool_list", bool_list)
print("my_list[bool_list]", my_list[bool_list])
```

Output:

```
  my_list [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
flag_list [0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0]
bool_list [False False  True  True  True False False  True  True False]
my_list[bool_list] [2 3 4 7 8]
```

If `flag_list` is a normal python list instead of a numpy array of zeros and ones, then we can convert directly to bool array

```
bool_list = np.array(flag_list, dtype='bool')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using **zip method** to solve the problem:

```
my_list = ['a','b','c','d','e']
flag_list = [0,0,1,0,1]
res = [i for i,j in zip(my_list,flag_list) if j==1]
print(res)
```

output:

```
['c', 'e']
```

Using **filter** method:

```
my_list = ['a','b','c','d','e']
flag_list = [0,0,1,0,1]
lst = list(filter(lambda x:x[1]==1,zip(my_list,flag_list)))
res = [i[0] for i in lst]
print(res)
```

output:

```
['c', 'e']
```